# How to have IE11 in Linux Guest on Win7 Host?

Tags: ie

I have a Linux Guest VM as my main dev enviroment on Win7 Host (using VirtualBox). 
Want to have IE11 in the Guest Linux VM where i have all other development tools. 
How can i achieve this?

Thanks much in advance,
Dus

Answer (score 0):

You could in your Linux Guest, install VirtualBox or VMWare, create a virtual machine, install Windows and run EI11 there, but this seems redundant.

Internet Explorer is a Windows program, and does not run in Linux.  There is a chance that IE may run in WINE, but it may not run well, or may fail in the next round of updates from Microsoft.